# Is an enum variant instance also a closure in Rust?

Tags: rust, enums, closures

While reading through the `nom` [examples](https://github.com/rust-bakery/nom/blob/7.1.3/examples/), I came across functions that where called with an enum variant instance even though they expected a closure.

[For example](https://github.com/rust-bakery/nom/blob/7.1.3/examples/json.rs#L166),  `map(boolean, JsonValue::Boolean)` instead of an expected closure like `map(boolean, |b| JsonValue::Boolean(b))`

Why does this work? Does the enum variant `JsonValue::Boolean` somehow coerce to the closure `|b| JsonValue::Boolean(b)`?

What is this behavior called?

I failed to reproduce it with an minimal example

```rs
enum Foo {
  Bar(bool)
}

fn apply<I, O>(v: I, f: FnMut(I) -> O) {
  f(v);
}

fn main() {
  apply(false, Foo::Bar);
}
```

Comment: enum **constructors** can be used as functions, just as tuple struct constructors can be.

Comment: Your original code works with some simple tweaks to pass and use a `FnMut` correctly: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ef512322adbd51fbe0bd1a3ed466d1d)